# Ramda.js refactoring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

I decided to code a simple todo app using Ramda, but I have been stuck with one refactoring related issue. Here're two functions that I think could be refactored:

```
const isItemCompleted = R.pipe(
    R.prop("states"),
    R.contains("completed")
)

const isItemEdited = R.pipe(
    R.prop("states"),
    R.contains("editing")
);
```

As you can see, there is some code duplication and this would get even messier if I had more states. I have been trying to isolate the duplicated functionality as such:

```
const statesContains = R.flip(R.pipe(
    R.prop('states'),
    R.contains()
))

//I would like to use it like this:
const isItemCompleted = statesContains("completed")
const isItemEdited = statesContains("editing")
```

But I just cannot wrap my head around this. I can make it work with different argument ordering, but I would like to follow the data-last rule to create concise functions.

The data being passed to these isItemCompleted and isItemEdited functions could be something like this:

```
let item = {states:["editing", "complete"]};
isItemCompleted(item); //true
```

Any (functional) ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to go with this.

Perhaps the most straightforward is

```
const statesContains = R.curry(
  (state, item) => R.contains(state, R.prop('states', item))
);

const isItemCompleted = statesContains("completed");
```

But it's reasonable to want to abstract this a bit, to allow the property to be searched to vary as well.  So you could write:

```
const propContains = R.curry(
  (propName, state, item) => R.contains(state, R.prop(propName, item))
);

const editorsContains = propContains('editors')
const edFred = editorsContains('fred');

// or edFred = propContains('editors', 'fred');
```

Both of these are reasonable.  But Ramda has a function which reads really well, and will serve these needs pretty well, [`where`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#where).  With this, you can simply write:

```
const isItemCompleted = R.where({states: R.contains('completed')});
```

This, I believe, is the simplest approach if you're looking for one-offs.  But both of the above could help you create reusable functions.

You can see all this in action in the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?code=const%20items%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7Bx%3A%20%27a%27%2C%20states%3A%20%5B%27completed%27%2C%20%27successful%27%5D%2C%20editors%3A%20%5B1%2C%203%2C%205%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bx%3A%20%27b%27%2C%20states%3A%20%5B%27queued%27%2C%20%27unassigned%27%2C%20%27brand-new%27%5D%2C%20editors%3A%20%5B2%2C%205%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bx%3A%20%27c%27%2C%20states%3A%20%5B%27editing%27%5D%2C%20editors%3A%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%204%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bx%3A%20%27d%27%2C%20states%3A%20%5B%27editing%27%2C%20%27final-draft%27%5D%2C%20editors%3A%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%204%2C%205%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bx%3A%20%27e%27%2C%20states%3A%20%5B%27rejected%27%2C%20%27completed%27%5D%2C%20editors%3A%20%5B3%2C%204%5D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bx%3A%20%27f%27%2C%20states%3A%20%5B%27unassigned%27%5D%2C%20editors%3A%20%5B%5D%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Alet%20statesContains%20%3D%20curry%28%0A%20%20%28state%2C%20item%29%20%3D%3E%20contains%28state%2C%20prop%28%27states%27%2C%20item%29%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20isItemCompleted%20%3D%20statesContains%28%22completed%22%29%3B%0Aconst%20isItemEdited%20%3D%20statesContains%28%22editing%22%29%3B%20%0Aconsole.log%28%27complete%27%2C%20filter%28isItemCompleted%2C%20items%29%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28%27edited%27%2C%20filter%28isItemEdited%2C%20items%29%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20propContains%20%3D%20curry%28%0A%20%20%28propName%2C%20state%2C%20item%29%20%3D%3E%20contains%28state%2C%20prop%28propName%2C%20item%29%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20editorsContains%20%3D%20propContains%28%27editors%27%29%0Aconst%20ed3%20%3D%20editorsContains%283%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28%27ed3%27%2C%20filter%28ed3%2C%20items%29%29%3B%0A%0A%0Aconst%20isUnassigned%20%3D%20where%28%7Bstates%3A%20contains%28%27unassigned%27%29%7D%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28%27unassigned%27%2C%20filter%28isUnassigned%2C%20items%29%29%3B)**